# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'public_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, validation, undefined

Hi im having a problem here, the function works perfectly, the verifications i did so it doesnt give me an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" but now i have a problem later, in the last return part of the function, how could i solve getting and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'public_id' of undefined" if i only upload between 1-5 images? if i upload 6 images it works perfectly, if i upload 2 it does upload tu cloudinary but it gives the error i said before in that part of the code. please thank you

```
create: async (req, res) => {


        var pinturaId = req.params.id;

        var imageloop=[];

        if(req.files.file0!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file0);
        }
        if(req.files.file1!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file1);
        }
        if(req.files.file2!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file2);
        }
        if(req.files.file3!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file3);
        }
        if(req.files.file4!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file4);
        }
        if(req.files.file5!=undefined){
            imageloop.push(req.files.file5);
        }

        var array = [];
        

        for (let i = 0; i < imageloop.length; i++) {

            await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imageloop[i].path, (err, result) => {

             array.push(result)
               

            });
        }

        if (pinturaId) {

            Pintura.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: pinturaId }, { new: true }, (err, paintUpdated) => {

                if (err || !paintUpdated) {
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: "Error",
                        message: "Error al guardar la imagen"
                    });
                }

                if (paintUpdated != null) {

                }

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: "Success",
                    paints: paintUpdated
                });
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: "Success",
                image: array[0].public_id + "." + array[0].format,
                imageurl: array[0].secure_url,
                image2: array[1].public_id + "." + array[1].format,
                image2url: array[1].secure_url,
                image3: array[2].public_id + "." + array[2].format,
                image3url: array[2].secure_url,
                image4: array[3].public_id + "." + array[3].format,
                image4url: array[3].secure_url,
                image5: array[4].public_id + "." + array[4].format,
                image5url: array[4].secure_url,
                image6: array[5].public_id + "." + array[5].format,
                image6url: array[5].secure_url
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you, I also saw you forgot to add an `await` before `.findOneAndUpdate`

rather than hard coding the keys you can just loop over the object, then at the end just dynamically build the response

```js
create: async (req, res) => {


        var pinturaId = req.params.id;

        var imageloop=[];

        if (req.files) {
          // loops over req.files
          Object.keys(req.files).map(key => {
            // check if the key name includes the substring "file"
            if (req.files[key] !== undefined && key.includes('file')) {
              imageloop.push(req.files[key]);
            }
          });
        }

        var array = [];
        

        for (let i = 0; i < imageloop.length; i++) {
          await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imageloop[i].path, (err, result) => {
            array.push(result)
          });
        }

        if (pinturaId) {
          // you forgot the "await" here
            await Pintura.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: pinturaId }, { new: true }, (err, paintUpdated) => {

                if (err || !paintUpdated) {
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: "Error",
                        message: "Error al guardar la imagen"
                    });
                }

                if (paintUpdated != null) {

                }

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: "Success",
                    paints: paintUpdated
                });
            });
        } else {
            const obj = {
              status: 'Success',
            }
            array.map((_n, index) => {
              obj[`image${index}`] = `${array[index].public_id}.${array[index].format}`
              obj[`image${index}url`] = array[index].secure_url
            })
            return res.status(200).send(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just a genius, thank you so much, it works, just for someone that sees this, first you forgot to close this "if (req.files[key] !== undefined && key.includes('file')" you missed a ")" them since the first image starts at 0 i have to of course change the model of the db in my front (angular) and in my backend from image to image0 and till 5, the same goes when im using *ngFor and all, obviously, and that's it, incredible, again, thank you so much

Comment: as a sidenote, i would suggest adopting a strict API response pattern like the following, my company started using this at the suggestion of a consultant years ago and it has been a staple for us - https://www.narwhl.com